# Trouble with overflow and also with after hover

Tags: flexbox, overflow, pseudo-element

I'm having two issues at once.   One, with my new layout, it seems that when I zoom in enough, the x-scroll bar doesn't appear anymore (it used to before I went to the flex layout.)   If I add "overflow: auto;" to the body style, then it will show up, but only if you scroll down to the very bottom, and that's not what I want.

Also, I tried a style where I could have the hover color go over the image instead of replacing it.  (I used the after element.)  It was working until I went to the flex layout.

(Also, is there a way to add scrolls to the other flex-item divs?  I don't know what conditions will force the "overflow: auto;" to come into effect.)

[code]

```
<html>
<head> 
<title> First Baptist Church of LaSalle </title>

   <!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
  <meta property="og:url"           content="http://firstbaptistchurchoflasalle.com/" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="First Baptist Church of LaSalle" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="The website of First Baptist Church of LaSalle" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="http://sprbc.org/images/banner1.jpg" />
<link rel="icon" href="./churchImage.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<style>

.headerDiv 
{
background-color: rgb(90, 7, 31);
width: 1000px;
height: 200px;
color: white;



}

body
{
background-color: beige;
//overflow: auto;

}



ul
{

height: auto;
width: 180px;
//background-color: #122213;
  border-style: solid;
    border-color: brown;
    border-width: 10px;
list-style-type: none;
background-image:url(./greenFelt.jpg);
//border-image-source: url(./wood.jpg);
border-image-width: 10px;
border-image: url(./wood.jpg) 30 stretch;
margin: 0;
//float: left;
}

 li
{

font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;

width: auto;
// background-size: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-family:  "Palatino Linotype", Serif;
position: relative;
background-image:url(./Crumpled_Paper_-_White.gif);
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
opacity: 1.0;
font-size: 12px;
 padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 8px;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;

 background-size: 100% 100%;



}




li a
{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;

}

li a:hover:after
{
 content:"\A";
    //width:97%;
     width: 92%;
    height:88%;
    background:rgba(143, 158, 208, 0.5);
    position:absolute;
 // top:0;
  top: 2.5;
   right: 0.0;
    left: 2.0;
    bottom: 0;


}

li:before
{

content: url(./pin.png);
 display: block;
    position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top:  0px;


}

li a:hover
{
//background-color: #2233dd;
// opacity: .9;

}

.flex-container {
   display: -webkit-inline-flex;
   display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;

}

.flex-item {

    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 2px;

}

#middle
{


font-family: "Palatino Linotype";
    font-size: 14px;
   font-style: italic;

}

#right
{

background-color: grey;

}

#container
{
overflow: auto;

}

</style>

<div style="width: 1000px;  height: auto; margin: 0 auto;" id="container">
    <div class="headerDiv">  <center><h1> First Baptist Church of LaSalle </h1></center> 
    </div>

    <div style="margin: 0; width: 1000px; border: 1px solid blue; height: auto; background-color: tan;" class="flex-container">
               <div class="flex-item w3-card-4">
                <ul style="width: auto;">
                    <li> <a href="http://www.firstbaptistchurchoflasalle.com/index.html"> Home</a></li><br/>
                            <li> <a href="http://www.firstbaptistchurchoflasalle.com/AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li><br/>
                    <li> <a href="http://www.firstbaptistchurchoflasalle.com/AboutUs.html">Pastoral Staff</a> </li><br/>
                    <li> <a href="http://www.firstbaptistchurchoflasalle.com/AboutUs.html">Sunday School </a></li><br/>
                    <li> <a href="http://www.firstbaptistchurchoflasalle.com/AboutUs.html">Services &amp; Directions</a></li><br/>
                    <li>  <a href="http://www.firstbaptistchurchoflasalle.com/AboutUs.html">Calendar </a></li><br/>
                    <li> <a href="http://www.firstbaptistchurchoflasalle.com/AboutUs.html">Activities</a> </li><br/>
                    <li>  <a href="http://www.firstbaptistchurchoflasalle.com/AboutUs.html">Contact Us </a></li><br/>
                    <li>  <a href="http://www.firstbaptistchurchoflasalle.com/AboutUs.html">Sermons </a></li><br/>
                    <li> <a href="http://www.firstbaptistchurchoflasalle.com/AboutUs.html">Weekly Bulletin </a></li><br/>
                </ul>
                 </div>
      <div class="flex-item" id="middle">
Dear Friends, <br><br/>
<p>Thank you for taking the time to visit our website for First Baptist Church of LaSalle. We invite you to take the time to look at the site and get to know a little bit about us. </p>

<p>First Baptist Church was started in 1839 and has been preaching the Word of God without compromise ever since. The church moved to its current location in 1976. </p>

<p>As pastor of the church, I have had the privilege of working with many wonderful people here at the church. God has blessed us with a great staff and many wonderful people in the congregation.</p>

<p>It is exciting to be here and to see what God is doing now and is going to do in the future. First Baptist Church is a church that cares about people and a place you can make home.</p>

<p>I would encourage you to come and see for yourself what God is doing here. My family and our church would love to see you.</p>

In Christ, <br></br>
Wesley Waddle, Pastor

      </div>

      <div class="flex-item w3-card-4" id="right">
<U>Contact Information </U><br></br>
<B> PHONE: </B> 815.223.1333 <br></br>
<B> FAX: </B> 815.223.1334 <br></br>
<br></br>
<B>ADDRESS: </B> 200 - 24th Street <br></br>
                      P. O. Box 1043  <br></br>
                      LaSalle, IL  61301 <br></br>
<br></br>



    </div>

</div>

<footer style="background-color: gold; width: 1000px; height: 200px; margin: 0;">
<center>  <div style="font-weight: bold;"> &copy; 2017 - First Baptist Church of LaSalle     </div>       </center>
<center><div class="flex-container">
<div class="fb-like flex-item" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/First-Baptist-Church-of-LaSalle-106794612807864/" data-width="80" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
<!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus flex-item" data-action="share" data-width="150" data-href="http://firstbaptistchurchoflasalle.com/"></div>

<!-- Place this tag after the last share tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
<div style="color: black;" class="flex-item"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Come visit our church!" data-size="large">Tweet</a> <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
</div>
</div> </center>
</footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[/code]

For the hover problem, it's not lining up to fully fit the image.  It's a big too   tall on the sides at the top.   (Originally, "Top: 0;  Left: 1.8;  Right: 0; Bottom: 0;  height: 100%; width: 97%;" worked, but now it doesn't with the new layout.)  (So I know there should be a  way to do it with just one style for all the li elements instead of having to having varying styles for each li element.)

Also, now that I recall, after I added the flex item to contain the UL and added the flex item to the flex container, I had to change my background-size: 100%; to background-size: 100% 100%;

to get it to fit all the words on the image and not go outside the image.

As for the scrolls, for some reason, the only ones I can get to show up, other than using overflow: scroll;  is overflow: auto; for body, and that only shows the x-scroll if you scroll to the very bottom.  (Interestingly, the y-scroll seems to be working fine.)  Applying overflow: auto;  to #container doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Adding "white-space: nowrap;" seemed to fix the problem, well, as much as possible, to the hover thing.   (It can't quite be perfect because the image would have to be perfectly rectangular, and it's not.)

Comment: However, the scrollbar is still not showing.